# How many table partitions is too many in Postgres?

Tags: performance, postgresql, partitioning

I'm partitioning a very large table that contains temporal data, and considering to what granularity I should make the partitions.  The Postgres [partition documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html) claims that "large numbers of partitions are likely to increase query planning time considerably" and recommends that partitioning be used with "up to perhaps a hundred" partitions.

Assuming my table holds ten years of data, if I partitioned by week I would end up with over 500 partitions.  Before I rule this out, I'd like to better understand what impact partition quantity has on query planning time.  Has anyone benchmarked this, or does anyone have an understanding of how this works internally?

Comment: They almost certainly would; I just picked weekly to get a larger number more realistically.  One could consider monthly partitions over 20 years instead.  I'm mainly interested in the constraints, and what the difference is between, i.e. 50 v.s. 100 partitions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The query planner has to do a linear search of the constraint information for every partition of tables used in the query, to figure out which are actually involved--the ones that can have rows needed for the data requested.  The number of query plans the planner considers grows exponentially as you join more tables.  So the exact spot where that linear search adds up to enough time to be troubling really depends on query complexity.  The more joins, the worse you will get hit by this.  The "up to a hundred" figure came from noting that query planning time was adding up to a non-trivial amount of time even on simpler queries around that point.  On web applications in particular, where latency of response time is important, that's a problem; thus the warning.

Can you support 500?  Sure.  But you are going to be searching every one of 500 check constraints for every query plan involving that table considered by the optimizer.  If query planning time isn't a concern for you, then maybe you don't care.  But most sites end up disliking the proportion of time spent on query planning with that many partitions, which is one reason why monthly partitioning is the standard for most data sets.  You can easily store 10 years of data, partitioned monthly, before you start crossing over into where planning overhead starts to be noticeable.

Comment: Over a decade later, I wonder how accurate the above statement is?

Comment: @ErwinWessels According to some comments [over here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239909/limits-of-table-partitioning-in-postgresql#comment473030_239909) things have significantly improved in PostgreSQL 12: *"hundreds of times faster in Postgres 12 than in 11, because of the improved partition planning"*. I would still recommend testing any specific use case though.

Answer (score 6):

> "large numbers of partitions are likely to increase query planning time considerably" and recommends that partitioning be used with "up to perhaps a hundred" partitions.

Because every extra partition will usually be tied to check constraints, and this will lead the planner to wonder which of the partitions need to be queried against. In a best case scenario, the planner identifies that you're only hitting a single partition and gets rid of the `append` step altogether.

In terms of rows, and as DNS and Seth have pointed out, your milage will vary with the hardware. Generally speaking, though, there's no significant difference between querying a 1M row table and a 10M row table -- especially if your hard drives allow for fast random access and if it's clustered (see the `cluster` statement) using the index that you're most frequently hitting.

Answer (score 2):

Each Table Partition takes up an inode on the file system. "Very large" is a relative term that depends on the performance characteristics of your file system of choice. If you want explicit performance benchmarks, you could probably look at various performance benchmarks of mails systems from your OS and FS of choice. Generally speaking, I wouldn't worry about it until you get in to the tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands of table spaces (using [dirhash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirhash) on FreeBSD's UFS2 would be win). Also note that this same limitation applies to DATABASES, TABLES or any other filesystem backed database object in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to trust the PostgreSQL developers who wrote the code, then I recommend that you simply try it yourself and run a few example queries with explain analyze and time them using different partition schemes.  Your specific hardware and software configuration is likely to dominate any answer in any case.

I'm assuming that the row optimization cache which the query optimizer uses to determine what joins and restrictions to use is stored with each partition, so it probably needs to load and read parts of each partition to plan the query.

Comment: I trust the developers, but their warning is very vague, so I'd like to understand it better.  My question, like most on Stack Overflow, was asked so that if someone already knows the answer, I don't have to spend hours building a representative test setup to reproduce their work.

Comment: @DNS It is vague because it depends on your hardware and software configuration, data, and queries.  An answer which is right for one person will not be right for another person.  SQL is subtle that way.